# Access anchor tag attribute inside iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Parent domain: www.parent.com
Iframe domain: www.iframe.com

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <iframe id="trick" src="www.iframe.com/test">
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <a href="www.test.com">test</a>  
      </body>
    </html>
  </body>
</html>
```

Question: how to access the value of href of anchor tag inside iframe using jquery?

Comment: You can't. It's called the same-origin policy. It's a security feature in all browsers, and you won't be able to circumvent it.

Answer (score 1):

Since they pages appear on different origins:

1. The page containing the frame needs to [listen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) for a Message event.
2. The page inside the frame needs to send a message using [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage).

This, obviously, requires changes on both sites. Explicit co-operation between the sites is required for obvious security reasons (if they aren't obvious, imagine your bank's website being loaded in an iframe by a random site you visited via Google).

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://simple.procoding.net/2008/03/21/how-to-access-iframe-in-jquery/

```
$('#iframeID').contents().find('#someID').html();
```

Comment: If so, maybe this link could help you: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-crossframe/